# Access File System of a WSL as a seperate Drive

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed **Ubuntu 20.04** from Microsoft Store as a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and I need to access the system files of it from Windows Explorer and access it as a **separate Partition** (as C:,D:).
Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is Linux File System. On WSL, as you have installed Ubuntu, You Can find it in,

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows\LocalState\rootfs

Comment: Thanks but i need this folder as a seperate partition!

Comment: It is more convenient and safe to use \\wsl$